# Does Tor Work With Secret Agent

Tags: anonymity, security

Does Tor Work With Secret Agent?  Secret Agent can be found [here](https://dephormation.org.uk/index.php?page=81).  Will Tor break and/or is it a bad idea?

Comment: Changing your user-agent like that will only make you less anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an odd idea, essentially it appears to just be a means of doubling down.... what it anonymizes or rather spoofs is usually already either masked or script disabled by TOR, that noted yes it should work. I tried and couldn't add it to any of my current browsers due to signature enforcements...

That noted there's almost no reason to run both at the same time as they have contradictory utilization purposes. If you really wanted to do it and knew enough to discern how you wanted to manually set both up... go for it, nothing ventured nothing gained, me personally I think it's too much effort for what I do but I just code monkey around. nothing serious or important... or legally questionable :P